# SQL Injection in my php code

Tags: php, mysql, security, sql-injection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

I want to know if my code has hacks like SQLI

```
function insertRow($table,$fields,$values)
    {
        if(count($fields) != count($values))
        {
            echo "fields and values must be the same count";
            return null;
        }
        $query = "INSERT INTO ".$table." SET ";
        foreach($fields as $key => $field)
        {
            $query = $query. "" . $field . " = '" . htmlspecialchars($values[$key], ENT_QUOTES) . "', ";
        }
        $query = substr($query,0,-2);

        if (!mysql_query($query, $this->con))
        {
            echo "Error : " . mysql_error($this->con)."<br />";
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

I use htmlspecialchars and I want to know if it is ok

Edit :

```
$fields = array("a","b","c");
$values = array($_POST["a"],$_POST["b"],$_POST["c"]);
$a = $dbc->insertRow("tbl_synagoge",$fields,$values);
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: `htmlspecialchars()` is for sanitizing _output_ data to the browser, not for sanitizing input.  We would need to see how this function is called to know if it is safe (though I suspect it is not), what's important is how `$fields, $values` get populated.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: Please go learn about PHP's multiple ways of preventing SQL injection, preferably the PDO module.  See http://bobby-tables.com/php.html

Comment: @AndyLester, I'm reconsidering recommendation of PDO since I found out PDO_mysql enables multi-query *by default*.  It's exactly what allows the "Bobby Tables" vulnerability.

Comment: More resources: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection, and http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/sql-injection-myths-and-fallacies

Comment: “if my code has hacks like SQLI”? It should be more like “if my code is vulnerable to SQLI”. Your code is the victim and not the actor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `htmlspecialchars()` use `mysql_real_escape_string()`.

This will make your code more secure.

However you might want to retire all your mysql_* functions as they are deprecated.  You can get started right here: [MySQLi](https://www.php.net/mysqli)

Comment: $secureValue = new security($values[$key]);
$secureValue = $secureValue->getSecureSQLInput();
$query = $query. "" . $field . " = '" . $secureValue . "', ";

Comment: public function getSecureSQLInput()
     {
         return mysql_real_escape_string($this->input);
     }

Comment: mysqli   <-  all mysql_ have been discontinued.  
Refer to mysqli or pdo.